# Compare two data streams without both being stored as files

Tags: command-substitution

I have these two files:-

```
[root@localhost base_filters]# cat aix_old
joe
amadeus
image
bill
juliet
charlie
romeo
ftp


[root@localhost base_filters]# cut -d: -f1 passwd2
henry
amadeus
image
bill
julie
jennifer
charlie
romeo
harry
```

I am trying to find out the differences between two files; so I am using the following command:-

```
[root@localhost base_filters]# cut -d: -f1 passwd2 | sort | diff `sort aix_old` -
```

But getting this following error:

```
diff: extra operand `charlie'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

I know I can use another temporary file for sorting the contents in `aix_old` but I don't want another temporary file; so tried with command substitution.

Any idea, what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With ksh, zsh or bash, using process substitution:

```
diff <(cut -d: -f1 passwd2 | sort) <(sort aix_old)
```

gives:

```
4,5c4
< harry
< henry
---
> ftp
7,8c6,7
< jennifer
< julie
---
> joe
> juliet
```

```
diff -y <(cut -d: -f1 passwd2 | sort) <(sort aix_old)
```

gives:

```
amadeus                              amadeus
bill                                bill
charlie                             charlie
harry                                 | ftp
henry                                 <
image                               image
jennifer                              | joe
julie                                 | juliet
romeo                               romeo
```

From the process substition wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution

> The Unix diff command normally accepts the names of two files to
>   compare, or one file name and standard input. Process substitution
>   allows you to compare the output of two programs directly:
>
> $ diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
>
> The `<(command)` expression tells the command interpreter to run command
>   and make its output appear as a file. The command can be any
>   arbitrarily complex shell command.

The same using [yash's *process redirection*](https://yash.osdn.jp/doc/redir.html#process) (on systems with `/dev/fd/n`):

```
diff /dev/fd/3 3<(cut -d: -f1 passwd2 | sort) /dev/fd/4 4<(sort aix_old)
```

Or more cumbersomely with any Bourne-like shell (on systems with `/dev/fd/n`):

```
cut -d: -f1 passwd2 | sort | {
  sort aix_old 3<&- | diff /dev/fd/3 -
} 3<&0
```